# Reindexing issue after upgrading to magento 2.3

Tags: magento2.3, reindex, eav-attributes

**Preconditions (*)**

1. Install Magento 2.2.x
2. Make custom multi-select product attribute with the source model

**Steps to reproduce (*)**

1. Upgrade above magento2.2.x to magento2.3.1
2. Reindex Data

**Expected result (*)**

1. Successful reindexing should happen for all indexers.

**Actual result (*)**

1. Got an error while reindexing Product EAV(catalog_product_attribute). The error which I got is:

> Warning: Illegal offset type in
>   vendor/magento/module-catalog/Model/ResourceModel/Product/Indexer/Eav/Source.php
>   line 351

Comment: reset indexer => php bin/magento indexer:reset and then do again reindexing

Comment: Tried but no luck!